# Multiple databases or one large database?

Tags: sql-server

My company has a framework where different areas of a region are created as separated databases - we call them datamarts. All of the databases are exactly the same and in some regions we have 20 -30 databases where some or all are included in a particular query. Is there a performance penalty when we perform queries that join these databases or does SQL Server join these cross database queries seamlessly. Some of the databases may have a few million transactions.

Comment: It depends on the info you need; normalize the info and have related stuff grouped together.

Answer (score 3):

Do the data marts need to have any of different schemas or different backup and recovery strategies? These would justify the separate databases.

Having these data marts has disadvantages:

- query performance degradation
- logical inconsistency

  - difficulty to enforce certain constraints between data-marts (unique, FK)
  - duplication of lookup data in each data mart, followed by drift of values
- (globally) inconsistent restores
- operational overhead
- HA/DR

Your post does not provide the reasoning why data marts were chosen, so I cannot judge what advantages were leveraged or expected.

For a more thorough discussion see [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx).

If you want performant queries on aggregated data from all data-marts, why not do just that? Aggregate the data-marts into a single DW, powered by columnstores, and enjoy performance.

Comment: The data marts have the same schema and are backed up in the same way. We have a separate database, called Central, which holds the lookup tables but obviously we lose referential integrity by doing it this way. I have asked if there was a business reason for doing it this way and there is none other than for security. However, applications can enforce those kinds of security rules as there are users who can view multiple data marts and there are times when organizations with transactions in one data mart need to be moved to another. @RemusRusanu, thanks for the article reference.

Answer (score 2):

Important Points from your Question

> Separate Database for different Regions.

Consider this as an extra security layer, Only the users who need data from other database get given permissions to access that data, others can carry on working without any efforts being made by the DBA to limit their access.

> Some Regions has 20-30 databases.

Some Regions has 20-30 database. Not all some may have only 1 or 2 database. Merging all this data from multiple database for multiple regions means you will end up with one HUGE database. Think about the maintenance tasks such as Indexing , Backups , restores. Issue with data for one region may very well means downtime for all the regions etc. so best to leave that data divided into smaller databases.

> Particular queries hit all the database.

Particular queries hit all the database, not all the queries. Assuming users from one region will mostly query data from their own region, yet sometime they would go out to other database to pull data from other regions, makes sense to keep database separate for different regions.

> Some database with few million Transactions.

Some database with few million transactions, in other words some very busy log files for some database extra care/maintenance required to manage only some log files. On the other hand one HUGE database with one HUGE very very very busy log file. A lot more maintenane required just because some of the regions being very busy an writing the living hell out of the log file.

"The Moral of the story" is breaking down a large amount of data into multiple database has a quite a few benefits where as on the other hand having a Large Huge database may very will give you some performance for them "some cross database" queries, but really is it worth the price you are paying for having one single database? Now you decide :)

Comment: Thank you. You've covered a bunch of considerations. Since the primary utility of our application is querying the database(s) the degree of performance hit by having multiple databases is critical. Also, with many databases, any database change needs to be managed to keep the schemas in sync. With a small team its a challenge to balance these considerations. Thank you for your thoughtful reply.